# Is it possible to open Expander from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have an `Expander` in my View that every time I touch it it opens and displays data. Is it possible to open the `Expander` or close it from ViewModel? What I want to do is that the `Expander` can open or close it by pressing a `Button`.

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView>
                            <Frame>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Expander x:Name="expander"></Expander>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <ImageButton Source="img1" Command="{Binding xxxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference expander}, Path=.}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
    xxxCommand = new Command((sender)=> {

     var exp = sender as Expander;
     exp.IsExpanded = !exp.IsExpanded;
     //...
            
});
```

When I open the app, I get this exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Can not find the object
> referenced by expander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the Expander  as parameter to the Command of the button .

**Set the name of Expander**

```
 <Expander x:Name="exp">
```

```
 <Button Text="XXX"  Command="{Binding xxxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference exp}, Path=.}" />
```

In ViewModel

```
xxxCommand = new Command((sender)=> {

     var exp = sender as Expander;
     exp.IsExpanded = !exp.IsExpanded;
     //...
            
});
```

### Update

In your case you could use Data binding

```
<StackLayout>
      <Expander  IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}"></Expander>
</StackLayout>
```

```
<ImageButton Source="img1" Command="{Binding xxxCommand}"/>
```

Add a new property in your model

```
public class YourModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            isExpanded= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
        }
    }


    //...other properties

}
```

#### In ViewModel

```
//list here is the ItemsSource of your listview
ObservableCollection<YourModel> list = new ObservableCollection<YourModel>();

//list.Add();
//list.Add();
//list.Add();
//list.Add();
```

```
Command xxxCommand = new Command(()=> {

   //if you want to open the first Expander  

   list[0].IsExpanded = true;


});
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. My application crashes because my Expander is inside a CollectionView, a Frame and StackLayout, and when putting its x: Name in the CommandParameter it tells me that it does not find anything called expander.

Comment: The Expander control is known to show unwanted behavior when used in a ListView or CollectionView. At this time we recommend not using a Expander in one of these controls.Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander

Comment: Check my update answer  . Don't forget to accept it if it helps you :)

Comment: Can't use list[0].IsExpanded = true; , I only can use IsExpanded = true; alone and it don't work, it is called but nothing change in the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227956/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-lololyut).